# rails to_param is not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am following Ryan Bates railscasts video of friendly url. I am trying to implement that on my **Category** model by overriding the `to_param`method.
Seems like it's not working, or I am missing something.
Below is my url before overriding:

```
localhost:3000/search?category_id=1
```

After overriding the `to_param` the url remained same.

Following is my code:

**Category model**

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  enum status: { inactive: 0, active: 1}
  acts_as_nested_set

  has_many :equipments, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :subs_equipments, :foreign_key => "sub_category_id", :class_name => "Equipment"
  has_many :wanted_equipments, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :services, dependent: :destroy

  validates :name, presence: true
  validates_uniqueness_of  :name,message: "Category with this name already exists", scope: :parent_id
  scope :active, -> { where(status: 1) }

  def sub_categories
    Category.where(:parent_id=>self.id)
  end

  def to_param
    "#{id} #{name}".parameterize
  end

end
```

**Controller**

```
def search_equipments
    begin
      if (params.keys & ['category_id', 'sub_category', 'manufacturer', 'country', 'state', 'keyword']).present?
        if params[:category_id].present?
          @category = Category.active.find params[:category_id]
        else
          @category = Category.active.find params[:sub_category] if params[:sub_category].present?
        end
        @root_categories = Category.active.roots
        @sub_categories = @category.children.active if params[:category_id].present?
        @sub_categories ||= {}
       Equipment.active.filter(params.slice(:manufacturer, :country, :state, :category_id, :sub_category, :keyword)).order("#{sort_column} #{sort_direction}, created_at desc").page(params[:page]).per(per_page_items)
      else
        redirect_to root_path
      end
    rescue Exception => e
      redirect_to root_path, :notice => "Something went wrong!"
    end
  end
```

**route.rb**

```
  get "/search" => 'welcome#search_equipments', as: :search_equipments
```

**index.html.erb**

The line which is generating the url

```
<%= search_equipments_path(:category_id => category.id ) %>
```

Comment: Your code doesn't indicate how you're trying to turn a `Category` into a URL. Without seeing how your actually building a URL, we can't tell you what is going wrong.

Comment: `<%= search_equipments_path(:category_id => category.id ) %>` @meagar Is this what you want?

Comment: Yes, please edit it into the question.

Comment: Edited @meagar now please undo the hold.

Answer (score 1):

You are generating URLs in such a way as to ignore your `to_param` method. You're explicitly passing a value of **only the ID** to be used as the `:category_id` segment of your URLs. If you want to use your `to_param`-generated ID, then you need to just pass the model to the path helper:

```
<%= search_equipments_path(category) %>
```

Comment: Now it is landing on `localhost:3000`